# Can't select vector layer QGIS Zonal Statistics

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, zonal-statistics

I'm running QGIS 3.4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.1.  I have a raster layer and a vector layer from a .shp file in the same CRS.  When The window pops up for zonal statistics, I can select my raster layer but when I click the dropdown box to select my vector layer, nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: The vector layer must contain polygons.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the list of vectors you have in your "Layers" does not satisfy the geometry type condition. If the algorithm requires polygons and all of your layers are of point and lines geometry types, nothing will appear in that drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is that you don't have a vector layer added to your project - check if you might have the vector layer that is temporary only (isn't exported/saved), they might not come up in the list either. If the above doesn't work, I'd only recommend restarting the software/your computer and testing whether this problem occurs in other projects.